# Version specification of visual studio for SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have `SSMS 2012` installed on my laptop.Now,I need to use Sql Server Integration services.So,I have to install `Microsoft Visual Studio`. Does it need any particular version of microsoft visual studio to run this feature?

Comment: I believe you actually need SQL Server Data Tools but it is a long and arduous journey to work out the correct version and where to download it

Answer (score 0):

Full Microsoft Visual Studio installation is not needed in order to be able to work with SQL Server Integration Services. SQL Server Data Tools is enough.

SSMS 2012 does not necessarily indicate that your SQL Server version is also 2012. If it is, then you have to install SQL Server Data Tools 2012 or newer.